# Error when I tried to create a template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to create a temple driven form, and I want to access the values from the form, but I received this error :

```
CreateNewTaskComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

This is my form:

```
<form #taskForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addANewTask(taskForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id">Task Id:</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="task.id"  type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="task.description"  type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="date">Date</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="task.date"  type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        <button (click)="cancel()" type="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
      </form>
```

And this is my component:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-create-new-task',
  templateUrl: './create-new-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-new-task.component.css']
})
export class CreateNewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  task: Task;

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  addANewTask(form) {
    console.log(form);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.task = new Task(); //This line solved the issue
  }

}
```

I want to access values from the form... Could you please, tell me want I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `task` has never been initialized in the code above.

Comment: is your Task a class or interface?

Comment: was an interface, now I changed it in a class

Comment: I changed it in a class an I did  task: Task = new Task(); and I received this error: error TS2693: 'Task' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: now it's working, I put the task: Task = new Task() in  ngOnInit()  method, can you explain me why it didn't work when I put it in the component ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact change you have made in order to make sure this works?

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have a component class, which implements `OnInit`. In most object-oriented environments one does the actual initialization inside the `constructor`, but not in Angular. In Angular, the constructor is initializing the class and not the component. [Read more](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/constructor-vs-ngoninit-angular-2-components-b1a33db0be65).

So, basically you have an event hook, which is `ngOnInit`, which runs shortly after the constructor and `ngOnInit` will actually initialize the component. Your template will try to use `task`, assuming it's a property of the component, but will only be able to do so if it's initialized for the component.

More about lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks